# Javascript: constructor function this keyword

Tags: javascript, function-constructor

What is the difference between the following two code segments:

```
function HelloService(){
  var service = this;
  service.itemList = []

  service.hello = function(){    
    return "Hello World!!";
  };

  service.addItem = function(){
    service.itemList.push(1);
  }
}
```

---

```
function HelloService(){
  var service = this;
  var itemList = [];

  var hello = function(){    
    return "Hello World!!";
  };

  service.addItem = function(){
    itemList.push(1);
  }

}
```

Because as far as I understand the `this` inside the hello function and outside the hello function points to the same instance.

Could someone explain the above problem w.r.t to JAVA?

EDIT: I have added an `addItem` function. Here I don't understand the difference between `service.itemList` and `var itemList` inside the `addItem function`. Could you explain the difference inside that function?

Comment: `this` inside the function, depends entirely on how you call the function

Comment: in the first one (with `this.hello`) you can call the hello function from the outside (`console.log(new HelloService().hello());`). In the second one hello is just a local variable, not accessible from the outside.

Comment: It is really worth reading up the exact meaning of "this" in JS.  Understand that it has almost nothing to do with any concept of class as in Java.  As adeneo says, it is about the call, not the declaration.

Comment: On the other hand, in the second example it doesn't matter what `this` is at all, as the variable has nothing to do with `this`.

Comment: Any tutorial on Javascript OOP will help you understand this.

Comment: What does this have to do with JAVA?

Comment: @Barmar see the edit

Comment: It doesn't matter if `this` is the same inside and outside the function, the function creates it's own scope, and the variable is declared in that scope, and as variables are function scoped, they are only accessible within that scope (or a "lower" scope).

Comment: @adeneo thanks!! Now, I understand. BTW I am new to JS and function inside function is little confusing

Answer (score 2):

Local variables in Javascript functions do not get added as properties of `this`. The first is equivalent to:

```
function HelloService(){
  this.hello = function(){    
    return "Hello World!!";
  };
}
```

But not:

```
function HelloService(){
  var hello = function(){    
    return "Hello World!!";
  };
}
```

Which does nothing since the function referenced by `hello` is never used and is not accessible outside the scope of HelloService.

Comment: Some further resources for learning about JS `this`: https://derickbailey.com/email-courses/masteringthis/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this, http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: `var varName="val";` is generally only equal to `this.varName="val";` when in the global context.

Comment: @chiliNUT - it's not about context or the value of `this`, but scope. When inside a function, even if `this` is the global, the variable won't be added to it -> https://jsfiddle.net/9ygu01nj/

Comment: @adeneo hey, II'm a little confused, I think we are in agreement, its obvious why your fiddle doesn't work; I use scope and context as synonyms, but clearly you are using them differently, if 2 variables are in the same scope, are they not in the same context? Please clarify :)

Comment: ie, in your example, `this` is the global object but clearly you are not in global scope, you are in a function's scope

Comment: @chiliNUT - sure, the global context is outside any function, and hence in the global scope, so I guess you're right